# Save text in database in yii2

Tags: database, yii2

I wanted to use the Persian language in the database through the yii2
i used :
views - > main.php

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and

```
<html lang="fa-IR">
```

but 
؟؟؟؟؟؟ is stored in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the table structure. Where you want to store `persian` text there `Collation` should be `utf8_unicode_ci`

below is the snapshot

[image: Collation = utf8_unicode_ci]

Comment: I put the collection on utf8_unicode_ci   && utf8_general_ci   && ....
but not work

Comment: charset' => 'utf8', put it in to your db configration file